# Angular pipe to raw html

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Im retrieving from my DB the following string: "P.5 ¿Conoce la `<strong><u>`OFICINA VIRTUAL`</u></strong>` de {TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_50}?" that I need to show as HTML with the `strong` and `u` raw labels.

Im sure I need to make a Pipe but have no idea how to do it using Angular 2 with cli, ¿any help?

Comment: No pipes necessary! You want to see a very popular QA already provided for this very topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding/32104766#32104766 `[innerHTML]="yourVar"`

Comment: thats magic!! thanks!!